# Realloc an array but do not lose the elements in it

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, realloc

Code:

```
int * data;
data = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
int i;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  data[i]=i;
int * aux;
aux = realloc(data,sizeof(int)*20);
if(aux)
   data=aux;
for(i=10;i<20;i++)
  data[i]=i;
```

A teacher once told me "No, you can't reallocate an array with elements without a backup"; I said, "Oh, OK", but now that make no sense to me.

The memory pointed by the pointer is already allocated so is "impossible" to lose it; if I make a safe `realloc` there should be no problem.

My question is: if I want to resize an dynamic array, is the above example code valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is OK. Just <sup><del>two</del></sup> three more things to make it perfect,

1. Check for `malloc()` success before using the returned pointer.
2. If `realloc()` fails, you should not be accessing the array with new dimension.
3. After this code block, it's difficult to find out whether the allocated memory for `data` has been changed (20) or not (10). So, the better approach is to instead of checking for not-NULL,

   - check for NULL as the returned pointer of `realloc()`
   - stop/return/abort if it's NULL [ or use the old dimension for further code, if you may]
   - continue with the new dimension otherwise.

Comment: There's at least one problem you have not pointed out— at the end of the fragment, you don't know whether the array is 10 or 20 elements long.  This makes the addition pointless.

Comment: At the statement after the code fragment, we can assume there is a non-null pointer to a chunk of data, but with your modification to the original code, you don't know how big that chunk of data is. It might be 20 because both the `malloc()` and `realloc()` succeeded; it might be 10 because the `malloc()` succeeded but the `realloc()` failed. Granted, your fix didn't write to the not-allocated memory (that's good!), but you don't know in the code that follows whether it is safe to access `data[10]` or not.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is not entirely valid.  Here's a partly annotated modified version:

```
size_t size = 10;  // Keep a record of the size of the array
int *data = malloc(sizeof(*data) * size);
if (data != 0)   // Always check that the allocation succeeds
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        data[i] = i;
    size_t new_size = size * 2;  // Grow arrays by doubling as a general rule
    int *aux = realloc(data, sizeof(*aux) * new_size);
    if (aux != 0)             // Test allocation - as you did anyway
    {
        data = aux;
        // Only initialize new data if successful
        for (size_t i = size; i < new_size; i++)
            data[i] = i;
        size = new_size;      // Record new size of array
    }
}

/* At this point, if data != 0, it is safe to access data[0]..data[size-1] */
```

You need to know how big the array is at the end of this fragment.  In this version, if `data` is not null, then `size` records its size.  (If data is null, you should probably be bailing out by now.)  In your original code, you didn't know what size the array was.  This was a major problem; you cannot use the array safely if you don't know how big it is.

The allocations use `sizeof(*data)` so that if the type of `data` changes (say to `double *data`), the rest of the `malloc()` statement does not have to change.  That's an advantage of not casting the result of `malloc()` or `realloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly ok. The final two lines of code, where you init the new values, need to be inside the if-statement in case the reallocation failed. Otherwise you're accessing your original buffer, which was only allocated for 10 elements, so you will end up accessing memory that doesn't belong to you.

Comment: There's at least one problem you have not pointed out— at the end of the fragment, you don't know whether the array is 10 or 20 elements long.  This makes the addition pointless.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - the whole code is pointless, we may consider this an artifact of the demo.

Comment: I thought my answer addressed exactly this problem. If `aux` is not `NULL`, then it's 20 elements; if it's `NULL`, the original (and still allocated) buffer is 10 elements, hence why accessing a second 10 elements is going beyond the end of the array and should be avoided (i.e. put inside the if-statement).

Comment: Well — I don't agree with @HenkHolterman or you, Jim .  At the statement after the code fragment, we can assume there is a non-null pointer to a chunk of data, but with your modification to the original code, you don't know how big that chunk of data is.  It might be 20 because both the `malloc()` and `realloc()` succeeded; it might be 10 because the `malloc()` succeeded but the `realloc()` failed.  Granted, your fix didn't write to the not-allocated memory (that's good!), but you don't know in the code that follows whether it is safe to access data[10] or not.

Comment: Oh, you mean in any subsequent code after what we are presented with in the OP. Sure, that's a correct statement, but I assume that the presented code is meant to be just a sample of generally how to deal with malloc/realloc. A production version should, of course, keep track of how many elements the buffer legitimately holds if it's meant to access them in a non-trivial way later. My answer only addresses the OP's specific question.